# How do multiple websites get same unique identifier from the same OpenID user/identify?

Tags: authentication, openid

We have a backend (RESTful) service for websites that depends upon uniquely identifying the same user across multiple, unrelated websites.  We have been using email address as the unique identifier, but email address is not always used by all websites, especially when OpenID authentication is by those websites.

So, does OpenID provide a unique identifier that would be the same across multiple Relying Parties (if the user authenticates with the same OpenID)?

If so, what would one instruct a series of independent website to provide us as a user identifier for each of their users if the goal was that multiple, unrelated websites provide the same identifier when they each have the same OpenID user?

Also, a goal is to make this as easy as possible for developers that will consume our APIs.  So, if you know of any good API documentation that has already solved this, links to that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about your web service or what language its written in, I'm not certain how helpful my answer will be as it will be fairly general and less technical.

OpenID providers responding to an identification/authorization request will respond with a "Claimed ID" and an "Identity" as well any "attribute exchanges" requested. The attribute exchange information can be things such as email/username/language/realname/etc that may be what you are looking for.

Google (as an OpenID provider) supports querying a decent number attribute exchange information, and provides a list in their documentation:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#Parameters

The OpenID Identity should be unique to a user, but may not cross-identify them to different websites even when issued from the same provider. (It can be a directed id unique to the RP it was issued to).
See more on this here:
[is openid.claimed_id static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052277/is-openid-claimed-id-static)

With all of this said, it is perfectly reasonable for you, as the designer of the API, to define that certain information (i.e. an email address) is required to consume the webservice. And then leave it to the parties that wish to use your webservice to somehow gain that information (directly asking a user, or through attribute exchange, etc).

---

For more information on OpenID I would look at their website, particularly the specifications and libraries:
http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html
http://openid.net/developers/libraries/

Libraries with some good documentation to use as a starting point include:

- JOpenID (Java):  http://code.google.com/p/jopenid/wiki/QuickStart
- LightOpenID (PHP):  http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/w/list

---

Implementing the OpenID authentication directly would not be applicable for a backend webservice since the end user has no involvement (i.e. could not supply credentials).

To meet your requirement of identifying the same user across various 3rd party websites you may need to become an OpenID *provider*. And then provide further API to allow functionality on 3rd party websites for users to link into their OpenID profile you manage.

Without being the actual provider of the identity... Sharing the OpenID identity with a 3rd party may be a potential security/privacy concern or in the very least against the specs of OpenID (which describes the exchange as a a shared secret between the RP and OP). Though it may be beyond the scope of what you wanted to do, being the OpenID provider would at least remove many of the privacy issues since the users would have to opt-in explicitly.

I'm not aware of any APIs that handle uniquely identifying users across multiple 3rd party websites without direct user interaction. Most webservices that I have written required either direct user credentials be supplied (for which the user was aware), or had to only identify a user as unique to a particular client. In the later case user authentication is not always necessary, the client could do a blanket authentication and then provide its own unique ID to track users, letting the the webservice be blind to what actually constitutes a user. Your requirements do not appear to fit into these common scenarios unfortunately.

---

One final thing to consider as you design your API...

Providing uniquely identifiable information (i.e. an email address) to a 3rd party may raise some eyebrows in the internet privacy ring. Especially if there is any financial gain to be had from the exchange (advertisments/directly-paying/etc) or if the use of the information is unknown/insecure or otherwise unwelcome.
http://www.ehow.com/about_5332990_legal-sell-email-list.html
http://www.aclu.org/technology-and-liberty/internet-privacy

You may want to ensure that your target clients (the consumers of your webservice) have the right jargon in their terms or can provide sufficient power to their users that allow them to opt-out of being submitted into your service. And make it clear what you are doing with the information...

Issues like that can be something that holds up acceptance of your API, so it is worth considering.